# Getting a private vector and its components C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I've been trying to override a method in a game. To do this, I need to get a private vector and its components. The vector in question is called viewShake and it has three components called x, y and z (of course).

The problem is, I can't use MethodInfo or FieldInfo or Vector3 as a variable type because it simply wont work. MethodInfo and FieldInfo don't work because I need to do math and Vector3 won't work because I can't use GetMethod() or GetField()

```
private FieldInfo viewShakeX;
private FieldInfo viewShakeZ;
private FieldInfo viewShakeY;

[Initializer]
public void Init()
{
    viewShakeX = typeof(PlayerAnimator).GetField("viewShake.x", ReflectionVariables.PrivateStatic);
    viewShakeZ = typeof(PlayerAnimator).GetField("viewShake.z", ReflectionVariables.PrivateStatic);
    viewShakeY = typeof(PlayerAnimator).GetField("viewShake.y", ReflectionVariables.PrivateStatic);
}

[Override(typeof(PlayerAnimator), "shake", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)]
public void OV_shake(float shake_x, float shake_y, float shake_z)
{
    if (MiscOptions.DisableShaking)
    {
        viewShakeX = 0;
        viewShakeZ = 0;
        viewShakeY = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        viewShakeX = viewShakeX + shake_x;
        viewShakeY = viewShakeY + shake_y;
        viewShakeZ = viewShakeZ + shake_z; 

}
```

(Ignore the Initialiser and Override attributes)

I am obviously quite new to C# as you can tell, so I'm sorry if I'm being stupid here. I've searched high and low, however and can't find what to do.

Comment: what exactly is this for? If you are `quite new to C#` than maybe reflection isn't something you should start with ...?

Comment: @derHugo Its not reflection that I'm primarily after. Like I said, its just an override for a game. I'm trying to disable shaking. The else is the original bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't obtain it in one step. You have to obtain the instance of the viewShake object first, then do more calls for the x, y and z components - relative to the viewShake object.